# How can I limit a Hive spatial binning query to a specific map extent?

Tags: big-data, hadoop, hive, spatial-framework-hadoop

I'm trying to do a HQL query based off a map extent. I cant get this to work, what am I doing wrong? I'm using the taxi_demo in the ESRI example.

SELECT ST_Bin(0.001, ST_Point(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude)) bin_id, *FROM taxi_demo WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Envelope(-8238484.195726455, 4969891.9664984355, -8235431.491909235, 4971962.932233592), ST_Point(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude))

Am I doing something wrong or fat fingering something? It says: No matching method for class com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Envelope with (double, double, double, double). Possible choices: FUNC(binary) [image]

Comment: What versions of Spatial Framework for Hadoop, Esri Geometry, Hive, and Hadoop?

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response.                                                                                              esri-geometry-api-1.2.1,spatial-sdk-hive-1.1.1, spatial-sdk-json-1.1.1, HDFS 2.7.1.2.3.4.29 , MapReduce2 2.7.1.2.3.4.29 , Hive 1.2.1.2.3.4.29